# Rails 2 - expected Hash (got Array) for param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in HTML if I made a form like this:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="categories[][name]" />
<input type="text" name="categories[][name]" />
<input type="text" name="categories[][name]" />
<input type="text" name="categories[][name]" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I expect `params[:categories]` to be

```
[{"name"=>"value"},{"name"=>"value"},{"name"=>"value"},{"name"=>"value"}]
```

But instead, rails 2 will raise a TypeError: expected Hash (got Array) for param

The error is raised here:

http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Utils/normalize_params

Why is this not allowed or not parseable in rails? What am I missing?

I know I could index the input like so

```
<input type="text" name="categories[0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="categories[1][name]" />
<input type="text" name="categories[2][name]" />
<input type="text" name="categories[3][name]" />
```

And get a Hash. But this seems counter-productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to reverse the subscript order:

```
<input type="text" name="categories[name][]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is a different outcome than what I want. I don't want just an Array. I want an Array of Hashes. I will clarify in my post.

Comment: nvm. You are right. I was stupid and confused... Need nap. :(